# Equivalent of Request.Form in Flash/Actionscript! Is it even possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a html page with a button and a textbox.
This page will post the details to another page that contains a swf file.

Is it possible for the flash to do a request.form (or equivalent) to retrieve the value of the textbox?

A colleague has suggested this can be done but can anyone tell me how?

Bex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POST data is submitted to the HTML page, not the swf itself.  As @Mathias suggested, you will need to pass the form data into the swf from within the HTML.  Using PHP and SWFObject, you can achieve what you are looking to do like this:

**FORM Page**

```
<form action="post_page.php" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

---

**SWF Page**

```
<div id="swf_holder"></div>
<script>
var flashvars = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("path/to/your/movie.swf", "swf_holder", "500", "500", "10.0.0","js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the SWF the data you got via POST or GET, the easiest way is to pass them to the swf like GET parameters. Just like you would do with sending additional parameters to a php file:

```
src="myflashApp.swf?myVar=1"
```

or in your case something like this:

```
src="myflashApp.swf?myvar=<?= $_GET['value'] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value via URL variables and read in in Flash via URLVariables class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html

Comment: So flash cannot do a get on a form post? I cannot pass it by url as users are not allowed to save it to their favourites. 
I was hoping that flash could grab the variable rather than the page and having to pass it in.